Disable Dual apps and second space on xiaomi's HyperOs
I need to disable permanently the features "Dual apps" and "Second space" on xiaomi's HyperOS.
By searching them on Activity launcher, I find they are supported by these activities:
dual app: com.miui.xspace.ui.activity.x
second space: com.miui.secuirityspace.ui.x
Can I safely disable/hide these through ADB?
(I tired via universal debloater but they don't show up..)
My doubt is that: for both activities "domains" I see few other activities that may not be directly linked with the features I want to turnoff. Will I create any troubles?
or, is there any other simpler way to achieve the same? thanks

by the way these activities are visible trough Activity Launcher, but they do not show up when I run  "adb shell pm list packages". Is that because they are part of another package, with a different name?
